# How to open a link in the "standard browser" from an Office Addin

Tags: office-js

It seems since Edge is now in place to render the Office.js based Office Addin we can't "force" the system to open a standard browser window.

Scenario:

Our Addin is hosted from https://company.com/webapp/officeaddin
We would like to add a link which points to http://company.com/webapp/something and this should be opened in the normal browser.

Problem:

With the current Office.js release it always opens a embedded browser window. In theory this is nice, but unfortunately we have a download section there, where the user can initiate a typical file download and this is not working inside this embedded browser window.

[image]

The link is created like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://company.com/webapp/something" class="btn btn-default btn-block"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> TEXT</a>
```

Is it possible to open the standard browser instead of this embedded browser from an Office Addin?

If not: Is there a way to "detect" that this the website is opened with this embedded browser so that we can avoid any links to the download stuff?

Comment: So you would like to let customer launch the browser to open the URL? and did this URL whitelist n AppDomain in manifest?

Comment: Yes - just the standard browser (e.g. the installed chrome/firefox/whatever) would be much better then the embedded browser. 
The URL is not configured as whitelist, but the domain itself is "kind of trusted", because the SourceLocation is configured like this:
<DefaultSettings>
<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://company.com/webclient/Officeaddin/Taskpane/"/>
</DefaultSettings>

The link that I would like to open in the default browser is something like this: https://company.com/webclient/something

Comment: Hello, have you found any solution for this ? I'm in the same situation and it's quite annoying

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using window.open(""). this should open the link in the default browser.

Comment: Yes - doesn't work. The target site is opened in the embedded browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on your scenario, but does this new troubleshooting note published last week help any?

[Edge browser - Get errors trying to download PDF file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins#get-errors-trying-to-download-a-pdf-file)

Comment: Is this "openBrowserWindow" method somewhere documented? My samples are not working, not sure if I'm on the latest bits.

Comment: Documentation has been delayed because it isn't yet supported in Outlook. The formal signature is: `Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow(url: string): void;` What issues are you having?

Comment: I tested it in 2 different ways: The addin from above is a "normal" web app and we invoke Office.js and we were unable to get this going with this method. Then I created a new Typescript based Office.js Addin with Yeoman and the method is unkown and because I didn't found any documentation I wasn't sure if this is really working.

Comment: If you are not working with Outlook, it should be  working. I'm finding your description of the symptoms vague. "not working" and "unable to get this going". What, specifically, happens when you call the `openBrowserWindow` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Office API to open in a browser window.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=common-js-preview#office-office-ui-openbrowserwindow-member(1)